# Setting up domain on VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, vps

I recently rented a virtual private server, I have installed apache with php and everything and it works fine, but I'm not sure how to setup my domain.

I have a domain at godaddy, so do i need to install nameserver on my VPS or can I just point godaddy to VPS ip adress somehow?

What if I want more than one domain, then i suppose nameserver is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, a nameserver is required however many domains you have pointing to one machine.

But you don't need to host it. You have 4 realistic options in total.

1. Most domain companies provide their own nameservers for you to use if you want. I'd be very surprised if GoDaddy didn't. Ask them.
2. Then there are third party DNS services like DynDNS or ZoneEdit. There are hundreds, if not thousands of services like this.
3. And then there's the possibility your VPS host has centralised DNS servers for their customers. I'm with Linode and they host all my DNS for me.
4. Failing that, you can always host it yourself on your server... If you only have one server, this is, frankly, a terrible idea. If the server dies (which they do from time to time) you lose very important DNS information (like MX email routing) as well as the website.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

My VPS host has DNS servers and it seems to be working fine now,
however I'm not sure how to setup domain to different subfolder instead of root apache folder.

I woud like, for example that

www.firstdomain.com points to "/var/www/"

and

www.seconddomain.com points to "/var/www/subfolder/"

Comment: I could hesitate a guess but I'm really not an Apache man. If you're looking for an easier-to-configure and much lighter server, take a look at Cherokee http://www.cherokee-project.com/

Comment: you'd probably need to use virtualhosts for that. I use ubuntu and debian derivatives have their own tools for apache virtualhosts, so, it'll depend on your distro

Answer (score 3):

GoDaddy provides DNS hosting, so all you have to do is creating 2 A records, one for YOURDOMAINNAME.TLD and another one www.YOURDOMAINNAME.TLD, both pointing to your VPS's IP address

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but have a read here in the FAQ:
http://www.zoneedit.com